# How can I check if a custom field was updated?

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom post named `vpn`. That custom post has a custom field named `company_location`.

Inside my functions.php file I am using the [updated_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta) hook to call a `bg_update` function I created.

I was expecting the function to `var_dump` the words `it works` at the top of my post edit screen after I change the `company_location` custom field on the post and click "update".

But nothing happens. No `var_dump` shows at all.

```
function bg_update ($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
    $test = "it works";
    if ($meta_key == "company_location") {
        var_dump($test);
    }
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bg_update', 10, 4 );
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This [question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94009/echo-or-print-r-in-an-admin-function) says that the post edit page redirects after loading, so you need to kill wp to see the var_dump. After playing with that I have found that this will kill wp and show the var_dump:

```
function bg_update ($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
    $test = "it works";
    var_dump($test);
    wp_die();
    if ($meta_key == "company_location") {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bg_update', 10, 4 );
```

But this does nothing. WP is not killed and the var_dump is not showing:

```
function bg_update ($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
    $test = "it works";
    if ($meta_key == "company_location") {
        var_dump($test);
        wp_die();
    }
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bg_update', 10, 4 );
```

So I now know that `updated_post_meta` is the correct hook because it is firing the function, but the problem is the IF statement is evaluating to false and therefore not running `var_dump`.

Why is that?

**UPDATE 2:**

I var_dumped `$meta_key` outside the IF statement and it's showing `string(10) "_edit_lock"`??

```
function bg_update ($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
    $test = "it works";
    var_dump($meta_key);
    wp_die();    
    if ($meta_key == "company_location") {
        // do things
    }
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bg_update', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Have you tried not using a var_dump but just `die($test);`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the priority of hook and number of arguments otherwise code is perfect. If you can update post meta for custom post type then you refer this.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta

Try Like this:

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bg_update', 10, 4 );

For custom post type EX: abc

<?php add_action( "updated_{$meta_type}_meta", $function_name', 10, 4 ); ?>

<?php add_action( "updated_abc_meta", $function_name', 10, 4 ); ?>
```

> UPDATE

```
function save_custom_field( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
//YOUR CODE
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Have tried this thanks, but still nothing shows for var_dump. The var_dump text does normally show on the post edit screen doesn't it?

Comment: after var_dump write exit; and check page is break or not?

Comment: When I put exit; outside the IF statement it breaks the page (shows all white, but no var_dump showing). When I put exit; inside the IF statement, directly after the var_dump, everything is the same (normal edit page, with no var_dump showing).

Comment: You can use default post type POST or any custom?

Comment: The custom field I'm updating is on a custom post type I created. Does that matter?

Comment: i think you can not read the the given reference link. you can use custom post type the hook will be change

Comment: Ohh I see. That bit confused me. I have changed that part to include my CPT name, but its still not showing the var_dump.

Comment: I think I see what has gone wrong. I might be using the wrong hook. I need a hook that fires after any of the post meta on the custom post type has been changed. But I think updated_post_meta has to specify the exact name of the meta being updated, like updated_CUSTOM-FEILD-NAME_meta. In that case, which hook should I use instead?

Comment: check update answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77680/discussion-between-patel-jignesh-and-tinytiger).